# Java and Android Suggestions For Better Learning

Tags: java, android, oop

So I hava `Java` this semester and I really want to ace it. `Java` feels much at home due to my little `C#` development background and I also started with `Android`. So I began learning `Java` and `Android` from :

- Ivor Horton'S Beginning Java
- Beginning Android 4 Games Development
- Beginning Android 4 Application Development

and for `OOP` concepts:

- Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming by Timothy Budd

I have already completed 30% of `Ivor Horton` and Budd and am loving it ! `Adroid` seems pretty catchable too.

So my query is, is there any other resource/book/site that I am missing to compliment my learning? If so what's it?

Comment: If you want to learn android. Check this : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: If you want to learn technical aspects then go for NewBoston here http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

It is a good reading for a novice (and experienced) java programmer.

Also study for [design patterns in java](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/)

And take a look at [Fowler's "Refactoring" book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672).

To understand how java works look at `src.zip` file, located in JDK installation folder. Unpack it and study source code of java standard classes. It will give you deep understanding how does java work.